# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ValueType' to 'int?'

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, nullable

I have a C++/CLI wrapper class to interop between C# and native C++. I'm getting a strange error related with `System.Nullable`. I understand that, for basic types, `System.Nullable<T>` is equivalent to `T?`. So I do this:

C#:

```
public int? RoboticsArmRotation {
   get { return mRobotics.ArmRotation; }
}
```

C++/CLI, interface:

```
virtual property System::Nullable<int>^ ArmRotation{ System::Nullable<int>^ get() = 0; }
```

C++/CLI, concrete class:

```
virtual property System::Nullable<int>^ ArmRotation {
    System::Nullable<int>^ get() {
        boost::optional<int> value = m_pNativeInstance->getArmRotation();
        return value.is_initialized()? gcnew System::Nullable<int>(value.get()) : gcnew System::Nullable<int>();
    }
}
```

But I get the title's compile error. Casting to `int?` solves it, but what bugs me is that it's saying `System.ValueType` when I defined my nullable as a reference. Can I leave the cast and move on, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is a value type, not a reference type.

Comment: I know nothing about managed C++, but are you sure you need `gcnew`? `Nullable<T>` is a value type, not a reference type. Will `gcnew` box, or does that only work for reference types?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen in C++/CLI you can work in a strongly typed way with boxed value-types, which is translated to `System.ValueType`(which is a reference type) and some metadata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `Nullable<int>^` which is a reference. Since references with a value type aren't directly supported by the runtime, the actual type at the IL level is `ValueType` that's tagged with `Nullable<int>^` in a way that C++/CLI supports, but C# doesn't. For C# it's just typed as `System.ValueType`.

This makes even less sense for nullables than for normal value types, since nullables get boxed as their underlying type.

I'd recommend not declaring the field as a reference in C++ either, but to use a simple `Nullable<int>`.